# Using Backup and Restore to transfer drupal configurations but not actual data

Tags: 7

I am trying to use backup and restore to transfer configurations in drupal, but not the actual data. The `backup and restore` module allows you to do a backup where you exclude data from certain tables. My question is does restoring have a similar option where you don't wipe all the data and just make changes without wiping all the data?

For example, on our staging instance we added a new field to the User Account called `field_phone_number`. Can I create a backup with the new field configuration on User Account and then "restore" this backup on our production instance without transferring actual user records?

Preferably, I would like to do this via drush so we can implement into our CI/CD process.

Comment: You should not try to move configuration or content between installations using direct queries to tables. There are many layers involved that may need different data on each installation. On D7 use features as the rist answer says, or configuration files on D8. For content, there are different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For drupal 7 the best way to transfer Drupal configurations but not actual data is to use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module.
You can create features from your staging env.
and then revert them in production.